# Send soap resuest from selenium webdriver

Tags: java, web-services, selenium-webdriver, soapui

I have an automation project for an application that in some test cases needs to send an invalidate request to an URL "http://localhost:9080/PaymentWebService", so I need to send the below request from selenium in the middle in a test case:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bus="http://Somewebsite.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <bus:processRequest>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <arg0>
        <Request>
           <SignonRq>
              <ClientDt>2011-06-08T12:00:00</ClientDt>
              <CustLangPref>en-gb</CustLangPref>
              <SuppressEcho>false</SuppressEcho>
              <SignonProfile>
                 <Sender>user</Sender>
                 <Receiver>60</Receiver>
                 <MsgCode>InvalidateCacheRq</MsgCode>
                 <Version>V1.0</Version>
              </SignonProfile>
           </SignonRq>
           <UtilSvcRq>
             <RqUID>824d115d8001</RqUID>
            <AsyncRqUID>111122332300</AsyncRqUID>
              <InvalidateCacheRq/>
           </UtilSvcRq>
        </Request>
     </arg0>
  </bus:processRequest>
```

Comment: What is the question? or issue to be specific?

Comment: Is not an issues. I need to send the above request from selenium.